# Port forwarding on AWS from the internet to private subnet instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to open server (instance) on private subnet on AWS that can be reached from the internet? It seems AWS has NAT instance but I was not able to find a way to set rule to forward to specific machine if request comes to a certain port.

Comment: Are you trying to SSH to an instance in a private subnet? If so, see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-session-manager/.

Comment: Thanks for the information but no I am not trying to ssh. It is for debugging purposes.

Comment: What does debugging involve in this case?

Comment: connect visual studio to resources hosted on that machine

Comment: Thanks. I will check both solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you (intentionally) cannot reach an instance in a private subnet.

One option is to launch a "Bastion Server" in a public subnet, then use SSH port forwarding so that a port on the private instance is magically attached to your local computer.

Example:

```
ssh -i KEYPAIR.pem -L 8000:PRIVATE-INSTANCE-IP:8000 ec2-user@EC2-IP-ADDRESS
```

This is actually just normal Linux stuff -- it is nothing specific to Amazon EC2.

Comment: I believe Amazon NAT is Linux based ? Is there a way to "customize" Amazon's NAT ?

Comment: There are two NAT options. One is a managed _NAT Gateway_ that has no configuration capabilities. Another is a _NAT Instance_ that is a normal Amazon EC2 instance with a configuration (IPTables Masquerade setting) that acts like a NAT. If you use an instance, you can always logon and configure other settings, such as a port forwarder from the public side to a resource in a private subnet. Not great for security, but it would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-load-balancer-private-ec2/) for that.

The load balancer will be public facing and will forward requests to your private instance.

Comment: I will look into it. It could be an overkill for what I need but, from what I see, it should work.

Comment: If it's for developers then John solution might be enough. If you want non technical people to access your instance, you might consider a ELB or going back to public subnet and expose your instance.